# Moving a line of code in many files from its current location in the file to the top

Tags: javascript, bash, command-line

I have hundreds of test files that are all named `index.test.js` in a repo. Every test file contains the following line of code:

```
import 'raf/polyfill';
```

It typically sits on line 5 in the file, but not always. I need to move it to the top position in every file without having to open them all manually. If there is already something in the top position it should bump that line down.

I was starting here based on a recommendation from a coworker, but it doesn’t target files with a specific filename.

```
for file in $(find . -mindepth 1 -type f); do sed -i 's/import\ 'raf/polyfill';//g' $file; sed -i '1s/^/import\ 'raf/polyfill';\n/' $file; done
```

Suggestions on a better method?

Answer (score 0):

I might use `ed` (not `sed`!) for this. Also, in general you should not iterate over the output of `find` in this fashion, as it will not work if there is a file with whitespace or glob metacharacters in its name. Just iterate over `*`, and skip non-regular files in the loop body.

```
for file in *; do
    [ -f "$file" ] &&
      ed "$file" <<EOF
/import 'raf\/polyfill';/m0
w
EOF
done
```

`ed` reads the commands to execute from its standard input. The `m` command moves a line matching the preceding regular expression to the line after its argument (0 being the beginning of the file, so the line is moved to the first line of the file). `w` writes the changes before exiting.

If you prefer something more compact, you can pipe the script to `ed` instead of reading from a here document:

```
printf "/import 'raf\/polyfill';/m0\nw\n" | ed "$file"
```

or take advantage of `bash`'s here strings and ANSI-quoted strings.

```
ed "$file" <<< $'/import \'raf\\/polyfill\';/m0\nw\n'
```